# Connect Ubuntu 11.10 from Mac Lion using NX Player

Tags: ubuntu, mac, ubuntu-unity, nx-client, nx

On Lion, only NX Player is supported, but if you are connecting to Ubuntu 11.10 that require Unity 2D, previously you can set something like "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
" in your NX Client's configuration.

But, seems NX Player is lacking of this flexibility to set this.

So, how to connect to Ubuntu 11.10 from Mac Lion?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [NX Server v4](http://www.nomachine.com/download-preview.php) on your Ubuntu server, which will support the Unity window manager just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenNX (http://opennx.net)

You also need to pass the argument `gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d` to the NX Client.